# How to not show all labels on ggplot axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to using `ggplot2` to plot this: [image]But as you can see on the x axis you can't read anything...

So how can I show on the x axis the value every 10 years, for example?

This is my command:

`ggplot(prova, aes(x=year, y=mass..g.)) + geom_line(aes(group = 1))`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Is your `year` column numeric? You can add `scale_x_continuous` with a `breaks` argument to specify where the x axis ticks should be. I can't tell what the range of years is in the image, but if it's from 1900 to 2000 (e.g.) you can do something like this:

```
ggplot(prova, aes(x=year, y=mass..g.)) +
    geom_line(aes(group=1)) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1900, 2000, 10))
```

Answer (score 36):

Fake data:

```
df = data.frame(year = as.factor(1800:2000),
                variable = rnorm(length(1800:2000)))
```

Your plot with fake data:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = variable, group = 1)) +
    geom_line()
```

The problem is that your year variable is a `factor` (or maybe a string?), so it's interpreted as categorical. You can work within this framework:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = variable, group = 1)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = levels(df$year)[c(T, rep(F, 9))])
```

Or, even better, you can convert it to numeric and things work automatically:

```
df$real_year = as.numeric(as.character(df$year))
ggplot(df, aes(x = real_year, y = variable)) +
    geom_line()
```

Notice that this, doing it "the right way", you don't have to bother with `group = 1` or mess with the scale. ggplot rewards you having your data in a proper format: fix your data and you won't have to fix your plot. If you want to make sure the labels are exactly every 10 years, you can use `scale_x_continuous` as suggested by user2034412, but by default it will make a good guess at "pretty" breaks in the axis.

If your x-axis is an actual date or datetime, something like `1984-10-31` then you should convert it to a `Date` object (or maybe a `POSIX` object if it has time as well), and again `ggplot` will then know how to handle it appropriately. See `?strftime` (base function) or the `lubridate` package for conversions to appropriate date classes.

Comment: What is the meaning of this? c(T, rep(F, 9))?

Comment: `T` and `F` are `TRUE` and `FALSE`. `rep(F, 9)` repeats `FALSE` 9 times. The `c` function concatenates. Altogether, `c(T, rep(F, 9))` makes 1 TRUE value followed by 9 FALSE values. Run that snippet in your R console to see.

Answer (score 14):

The other answers have covered the case where your dates are numerical years, but if (as @Gregor notes) your dates are actual `Date` objects, it's a lot easier:

```
scale_x_date(name = 'My date axis title', date_breaks = '20 years',
        date_labels = '%Y')
```

With [`scale_date`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html), you can control the breaks with intuitive language and the labelling with (hopefully) familiar [`strptime` notation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.0/topics/strptime).

Answer (score 3):

If you do not have too many datapoint you can do like this:

Fake data:

```
df = data.frame(year = as.factor(1990:2000),variable = 
rnorm(length(1990:2000)))
```

Normal plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = variable, group = 1)) + geom_line()
```

Plot with hidden labels:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = variable, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(color=c("black","transparent","transparent","transparent","black","transparent","transparent","transparent","transparent","transparent","black")))
```

Comment: If you have a longer string of points, you can print every `m` label for total categories where `n` = <total categories>/`m`.
+theme(axis.text.x=element_text(color=rep(c("black", rep("transparent", each =`m-1`)), `n`)))
and if desired add some 'transparent' to beginning or end of vector to offset the label or handle total  pints not a multiple of `m`