# R lubridate interval class for labeling axis

Tags: r, dplyr, label, axis, lubridate

This is my "old" method of creating a label vector for labeling the axis of a plot.

```
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)

#old
version <- "201710" 
endDate = as.Date(paste0(version,"01"), "%Y%m%d")                                         
startDateString = paste0(as.integer(substr(version, 1, 4)) - 3,substr(version, 5, 6))  
startDate = as.Date(paste0(startDateString,"01"), "%Y%m%d")                               
datehv <- format(seq(startDate, endDate, "3 months"), "%Y-%m")                            

zeitbereich = c()                                    
for(i in 1:(length(datehv)-1)) {              
  zeitbereich = c(zeitbereich, datehv[i], "", "")       
}
  zeitbereich = c(zeitbereich, datehv[length(datehv)])
labels <- substr(zeitbereich,1,7)
```

Below is the new version. The idea is to use lubridate and dplyr for better readability and a simpler syntax

```
#new
version2 <- "201710"  
endDate2 = ymd(paste0(version,"01"))
startDate2 = endDate2 - dyears(3)
zeitbereich2 <- interval(startDate2, endDate2)
```

How can I get the vector "labels" as in the old code to be generated from the new time interval?

a) ignoring the "" spots in the labels vector of #old

b) incorporating empty "" in the labels vector

Comment: are you then going to use this to label a ggplot?  you might be better changing this in the theme?

Comment: thats a good question: the plot is quite complicated and is currently in base r. i don´t know if the plot can be done like that in ggplot... (consisting of a line, a boxplot and a custom scale of rectangles that change the fill color depending on the value on a given time point.

but how is that something to be done via themes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep dates as dates.  Use the `seq.Date` function to add quarterly information, then change the format at the end.

I wouldn't change your loop, from what I can see it's the best solution for adding blanks, that said, I would assess why you need these blanks, there's probably a better way that doesn't require them.

```
st <- as.Date("20140101", "%Y%m%d")
en <- as.Date("20170101", "%Y%m%d")

quarters <- seq.Date(from = st, to = en, "quarter")

readable <- format(quarters, as.character("%Y-%m"))

zeitbereich = c()                                    
for(i in 1:(length(readable)-1)) {              
  zeitbereich = c(zeitbereich, readable[i], "", "")       
}
zeitbereich = c(zeitbereich, readable[length(readable)])
```

Comment: I need the blanks for nonlabelled ticks in the graph, because it wouldn´t look too good otehrwise. (its purely cosmetic). But you are probably right about a better option for this. I´ll need to look into it.

Comment: @alx if you put your graph code up would be happy to take a look?  probably best to do it in a separate question though.  good luck

Comment: I found this option that might be of help once I got a date format to work with.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732597/how-to-not-show-all-labels-on-ggplot-axis

Answer (score 1):

So in the end I did.

```
df2 <- data.frame(
  date = seq(Sys.Date(), len=100, by="1 day")[sample(100, 50)],
  price = runif(50)
)
df2 <- df2[order(df$date), ]

st2 <- ymd("19960101")
en2 <- ymd("20000201")
months2 <- seq.Date(from = st2, to = en2, by = "month")

mutate(df2, date=months2)

b <- ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=price)) + geom_line()
b + scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 months")
```

The datecolumn needs to be date class for scale_x_date to work. But like that it is possible to set the date brekas to whatever needed ("3 years" for example).