# Show alternate categorical labels in axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I know there are some questions issuing this problem in this forum, [as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732597/how-to-not-show-all-labels-on-ggplot-axis). However, my code is a little bit more complicated by using the package `forcats`.

To make my example reproducible, let's see two related datasets:

```
comb <- c("C if dm2dm1I1I2P3P4M1", "dm1 if dm2I1I2CP3P4M1", "dm2 if dm1I2I1CP3P4M1", 
"I1 if dm2dm1I2CP3P4M1", "I2 if dm2dm1I1CP3P4M1", "M1 if dm2dm1I1I2CP3P4", 
"P3 if dm2dm1I1I2CP4M1", "P4 if dm2dm1I1I2CP3M1", "CM1 if dm1dm2I1I2P3P4", 
"CP3 if dm1dm2I1I2P4M1", "CP4 if dm1dm2I1I2P3M1", "dm1C if dm2I1I2P3P4M1", 
"dm1dm2 if I1I2CP3P4M1", "dm1I1 if dm2I2CP3P4M1", "dm1I2 if dm2I1CP3P4M1", 
"dm1M1 if dm2I1I2CP3P4", "dm1P3 if dm2I1I2CP4M1", "dm1P4 if dm2I1I2CP3M1", 
"dm2C if dm1I1I2P3P4M1", "dm2I1 if dm1I2CP3P4M1", "dm2I2 if dm1I1CP3P4M1", 
"dm2M1 if dm1I1I2CP3P4", "dm2P3 if dm1I1I2CP4M1", "dm2P4 if dm1I1I2CP3M1", 
"I1C if dm1dm2I2P3P4M1", "I1I2 if dm1dm2CP3P4M1", "I1M1 if dm1dm2I2CP3P4", 
"I1P3 if dm1dm2I2CP4M1", "I1P4 if dm1dm2I2CP3M1", "I2C if dm1dm2I1P3P4M1", 
"I2M1 if dm1dm2I1CP3P4", "I2P3 if dm1dm2I1CP4M1", "I2P4 if dm1dm2I1CP3M1", 
"P3M1 if dm1dm2I1I2CP4", "P3P4 if dm1dm2I1I2CM1", "P4M1 if dm1dm2I1I2CP3", 
"CP3M1 if dm1dm2I1I2P4", "CP3P4 if dm1dm2I1I2M1", "CP4M1 if dm1dm2I1I2P3", 
"dm1CM1 if dm2I1I2P3P4", "dm1CP3 if dm2I1I2P4M1", "dm1CP4 if dm2I1I2P3M1", 
"dm1dm2C if I1I2P3P4M1", "dm1dm2I1 if I2CP3P4M1", "dm1dm2I2 if I1CP3P4M1", 
"dm1dm2M1 if I1I2CP3P4", "dm1dm2P3 if I1I2CP4M1", "dm1dm2P4 if I1I2CP3M1", 
"dm1I1C if dm2I2P3P4M1", "dm1I1I2 if dm2CP3P4M1", "dm1I1M1 if dm2I2CP3P4", 
"dm1I1P3 if dm2I2CP4M1", "dm1I1P4 if dm2I2CP3M1", "dm1I2C if dm2I1P3P4M1", 
"dm1I2M1 if dm2I1CP3P4", "dm1I2P3 if dm2I1CP4M1", "dm1I2P4 if dm2I1CP3M1", 
"dm1P3M1 if dm2I1I2CP4", "dm1P3P4 if dm2I1I2CM1", "dm1P4M1 if dm2I1I2CP3", 
"dm2CM1 if dm1I1I2P3P4", "dm2CP3 if dm1I1I2P4M1", "dm2CP4 if dm1I1I2P3M1", 
"dm2I1C if dm1I2P3P4M1", "dm2I1I2 if dm1CP3P4M1", "dm2I1M1 if dm1I2CP3P4", 
"dm2I1P3 if dm1I2CP4M1", "dm2I1P4 if dm1I2CP3M1", "dm2I2C if dm1I1P3P4M1", 
"dm2I2M1 if dm1I1CP3P4", "dm2I2P3 if dm1I1CP4M1", "dm2I2P4 if dm1I1CP3M1", 
"dm2P3M1 if dm1I1I2CP4", "dm2P3P4 if dm1I1I2CM1", "dm2P4M1 if dm1I1I2CP3", 
"I1CM1 if dm1dm2I2P3P4", "I1CP3 if dm1dm2I2P4M1", "I1CP4 if dm1dm2I2P3M1", 
"I1I2C if dm1dm2P3P4M1", "I1I2M1 if dm1dm2CP3P4", "I1I2P3 if dm1dm2CP4M1", 
"I1I2P4 if dm1dm2CP3M1", "I1P3M1 if dm1dm2I2CP4", "I1P3P4 if dm1dm2I2CM1", 
"I1P4M1 if dm1dm2I2CP3", "I2CM1 if dm1dm2I1P3P4", "I2CP3 if dm1dm2I1P4M1", 
"I2CP4 if dm1dm2I1P3M1", "I2P3M1 if dm1dm2I1CP4", "I2P3P4 if dm1dm2I1CM1", 
"I2P4M1 if dm1dm2I1CP3", "P3P4M1 if dm1dm2I1I2C", "CP3P4M1 if dm1dm2I1I2", 
"dm1CP3M1 if dm2I1I2P4", "dm1CP3P4 if dm2I1I2M1", "dm1CP4M1 if dm2I1I2P3", 
"dm1dm2CM1 if I1I2P3P4", "dm1dm2CP3 if I1I2P4M1", "dm1dm2CP4 if I1I2P3M1", 
"dm1dm2I1C if I2P3P4M1", "dm1dm2I1I2 if CP3P4M1", "dm1dm2I1M1 if I2CP3P4", 
"dm1dm2I1P3 if I2CP4M1", "dm1dm2I1P4 if I2CP3M1", "dm1dm2I2C if I1P3P4M1", 
"dm1dm2I2M1 if I1CP3P4", "dm1dm2I2P3 if I1CP4M1", "dm1dm2I2P4 if I1CP3M1", 
"dm1dm2P3M1 if I1I2CP4", "dm1dm2P3P4 if I1I2CM1", "dm1dm2P4M1 if I1I2CP3", 
"dm1I1CM1 if dm2I2P3P4", "dm1I1CP3 if dm2I2P4M1", "dm1I1CP4 if dm2I2P3M1", 
"dm1I1I2C if dm2P3P4M1", "dm1I1I2M1 if dm2CP3P4", "dm1I1I2P3 if dm2CP4M1", 
"dm1I1I2P4 if dm2CP3M1", "dm1I1P3M1 if dm2I2CP4", "dm1I1P3P4 if dm2I2CM1", 
"dm1I1P4M1 if dm2I2CP3", "dm1I2CM1 if dm2I1P3P4", "dm1I2CP3 if dm2I1P4M1", 
"dm1I2CP4 if dm2I1P3M1", "dm1I2P3M1 if dm2I1CP4", "dm1I2P3P4 if dm2I1CM1", 
"dm1I2P4M1 if dm2I1CP3", "dm1P3P4M1 if dm2I1I2C", "dm2CP3M1 if dm1I1I2P4", 
"dm2CP3P4 if dm1I1I2M1", "dm2CP4M1 if dm1I1I2P3", "dm2I1CM1 if dm1I2P3P4", 
"dm2I1CP3 if dm1I2P4M1", "dm2I1CP4 if dm1I2P3M1", "dm2I1I2C if dm1P3P4M1", 
"dm2I1I2M1 if dm1CP3P4", "dm2I1I2P3 if dm1CP4M1", "dm2I1I2P4 if dm1CP3M1", 
"dm2I1P3M1 if dm1I2CP4", "dm2I1P3P4 if dm1I2CM1", "dm2I1P4M1 if dm1I2CP3", 
"dm2I2CM1 if dm1I1P3P4", "dm2I2CP3 if dm1I1P4M1", "dm2I2CP4 if dm1I1P3M1", 
"dm2I2P3M1 if dm1I1CP4", "dm2I2P3P4 if dm1I1CM1", "dm2I2P4M1 if dm1I1CP3", 
"dm2P3P4M1 if dm1I1I2C", "I1CP3M1 if dm1dm2I2P4", "I1CP3P4 if dm1dm2I2M1", 
"I1CP4M1 if dm1dm2I2P3", "I1I2CM1 if dm1dm2P3P4", "I1I2CP3 if dm1dm2P4M1", 
"I1I2CP4 if dm1dm2P3M1", "I1I2P3M1 if dm1dm2CP4", "I1I2P3P4 if dm1dm2CM1", 
"I1I2P4M1 if dm1dm2CP3", "I1P3P4M1 if dm1dm2I2C", "I2CP3 M1if dm1dm2I1P4", 
"I2CP3P4 if dm1dm2I1M1", "I2CP4M1 if dm1dm2I1P3", "I2P3P4M1 if dm1dm2I1C", 
"dm1CP3P4M1 if dm2I1I2", "dm1dm2CP3M1 if I1I2P4", "dm1dm2CP3P4 if I1I2M1", 
"dm1dm2CP4M1 if I1I2P3", "dm1dm2I1CM1 if I2P3P4", "dm1dm2I1CP3 if I2P4M1", 
"dm1dm2I1CP4 if I2P3M1", "dm1dm2I1I2C if P3P4M1", "dm1dm2I1I2M1 if CP3P4", 
"dm1dm2I1I2P3 if CP4M1", "dm1dm2I1I2P4 if CP3M1", "dm1dm2I1P3M1 if I2CP4", 
"dm1dm2I1P3P4 if I2CM1", "dm1dm2I1P4M1 if I2CP3", "dm1dm2I2CM1 if I1P3P4", 
"dm1dm2I2CP3 if I1P4M1", "dm1dm2I2CP4 if I1P3M1", "dm1dm2I2P3M1 if I1CP4", 
"dm1dm2I2P3P4 if I1CM1", "dm1dm2I2P4M1 if I1CP3", "dm1dm2P3P4M1 if I1I2C", 
"dm1I1CP3M1 if dm2I2P4", "dm1I1CP3P4 if dm2I2M1", "dm1I1CP4M1 if dm2I2P3", 
"dm1I1I2CM1 if dm2P3P4", "dm1I1I2CP3 if dm2P4M1", "dm1I1I2CP4 if dm2P3M1", 
"dm1I1I2P3M1 if dm2CP4", "dm1I1I2P3P4 if dm2CM1", "dm1I1I2P4M1 if dm2CP3", 
"dm1I1P3P4M1 if dm2I2C", "dm1I2CP3M1 if dm2I1P4", "dm1I2CP3P4 if dm2I1M1", 
"dm1I2CP4M1 if dm2I1P3", "dm1I2P3P4M1 if dm2I1C", "dm2CP3P4M1 if dm1I1I2", 
"dm2I1CP3M1 if dm1I2P4", "dm2I1CP3P4 if dm1I2M1", "dm2I1CP4M1 if dm1I2P3", 
"dm2I1I2CM1 if dm1P3P4", "dm2I1I2CP3 if dm1P4M1", "dm2I1I2CP4 if dm1P3M1", 
"dm2I1I2P3M1 if dm1CP4", "dm2I1I2P3P4 if dm1CM1", "dm2I1I2P4M1 if dm1CP3", 
"dm2I1P3P4M1 if dm1I2C", "dm2I2CP3M1 if dm1I1P4", "dm2I2CP3P4 if dm1I1M1", 
"dm2I2CP4M1 if dm1I1P3", "dm2I2P3P4M1 if dm1I1C", "I1CP3P4M1 if dm1dm2I2", 
"I1I2CP3M1 if dm1dm2P4", "I1I2CP3P4 if dm1dm2M1", "I1I2CP4M1 if dm1dm2P3", 
"I1I2P3P4M1 if dm1dm2C", "I2CP3P4M1 if dm1dm2I1", "dm1dm2CP3P4M1 if I1I2", 
"dm1dm2I1CP3M1 if I2P4", "dm1dm2I1CP3P4 if I2M1", "dm1dm2I1CP4M1 if I2P3", 
"dm1dm2I1I2CM1 if P3P4", "dm1dm2I1I2CP3 if P4M1", "dm1dm2I1I2CP4 if P3M1", 
"dm1dm2I1I2P3M1 if CP4", "dm1dm2I1I2P3P4 if CM1", "dm1dm2I1I2P4M1 if CP3", 
"dm1dm2I1P3P4M1 if I2C", "dm1dm2I2CP3M1 if I1P4", "dm1dm2I2CP3P4 if I1M1", 
"dm1dm2I2CP4M1 if I1P3", "dm1dm2I2P3P4M1 if I1C", "dm1I1CP3P4M1 if dm2I2", 
"dm1I1I2CP3M1 if dm2P4", "dm1I1I2CP3P4 if dm2M1", "dm1I1I2CP4M1 if dm2P3", 
"dm1I1I2P3P4M1 if dm2C", "dm1I2CP3P4M1 if dm2I1", "dm2I1CP3P4M1 if dm1I2", 
"dm2I1I2CP3M1 if dm1P4", "dm2I1I2CP3P4 if dm1M1", "dm2I1I2CP4M1 if dm1P3", 
"dm2I1I2P3P4M1 if dm1C", "dm2I2CP3P4M1 if dm1I1", "I1I2CP3P4M1 if dm1dm2", 
"dm1I2I1CP3P4M1 if dm2", "dm2dm1I1CP3P4M1 if I2", "dm2dm1I1I2CP3M1 if P4", 
"dm2dm1I1I2CP3P4 if M1", "dm2dm1I1I2CP4M1 if P3", "dm2dm1I1I2P3P4M1 if C", 
"dm2dm1I2CP3P4M1 if I1", "dm2I1I2CP3P4M1 if dm1")

test <- structure(list(Type = c("1 vs. 7", "1 vs. 7", "1 vs. 7", "1 vs. 7", 
"1 vs. 7", "1 vs. 7", "1 vs. 7", "1 vs. 7", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", 
"2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", 
"2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", 
"2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", 
"2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", 
"2 vs. 6", "2 vs. 6", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", 
"3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", 
"3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", 
"3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", 
"3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", 
"3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", 
"3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", 
"3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", 
"3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", 
"3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "3 vs. 5", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", 
"4 vs. 4", "4 vs. 4", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", 
"5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", 
"5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", 
"5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", 
"5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", 
"5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", 
"5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", 
"5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", 
"5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", 
"5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "5 vs. 3", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", 
"6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", 
"6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", 
"6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", 
"6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", 
"6 vs. 2", "6 vs. 2", "7 vs. 1", "7 vs. 1", "7 vs. 1", "7 vs. 1", 
"7 vs. 1", "7 vs. 1", "7 vs. 1", "7 vs. 1"), Combination = c("C if dm2dm1I1I2P3P4M1", 
"dm1 if dm2I1I2CP3P4M1", "dm2 if dm1I2I1CP3P4M1", "I1 if dm2dm1I2CP3P4M1", 
"I2 if dm2dm1I1CP3P4M1", "M1 if dm2dm1I1I2CP3P4", "P3 if dm2dm1I1I2CP4M1", 
"P4 if dm2dm1I1I2CP3M1", "CM1 if dm1dm2I1I2P3P4", "CP3 if dm1dm2I1I2P4M1", 
"CP4 if dm1dm2I1I2P3M1", "dm1C if dm2I1I2P3P4M1", "dm1dm2 if I1I2CP3P4M1", 
"dm1I1 if dm2I2CP3P4M1", "dm1I2 if dm2I1CP3P4M1", "dm1M1 if dm2I1I2CP3P4", 
"dm1P3 if dm2I1I2CP4M1", "dm1P4 if dm2I1I2CP3M1", "dm2C if dm1I1I2P3P4M1", 
"dm2I1 if dm1I2CP3P4M1", "dm2I2 if dm1I1CP3P4M1", "dm2M1 if dm1I1I2CP3P4", 
"dm2P3 if dm1I1I2CP4M1", "dm2P4 if dm1I1I2CP3M1", "I1C if dm1dm2I2P3P4M1", 
"I1I2 if dm1dm2CP3P4M1", "I1M1 if dm1dm2I2CP3P4", "I1P3 if dm1dm2I2CP4M1", 
"I1P4 if dm1dm2I2CP3M1", "I2C if dm1dm2I1P3P4M1", "I2M1 if dm1dm2I1CP3P4", 
"I2P3 if dm1dm2I1CP4M1", "I2P4 if dm1dm2I1CP3M1", "P3M1 if dm1dm2I1I2CP4", 
"P3P4 if dm1dm2I1I2CM1", "P4M1 if dm1dm2I1I2CP3", "CP3M1 if dm1dm2I1I2P4", 
"CP3P4 if dm1dm2I1I2M1", "CP4M1 if dm1dm2I1I2P3", "dm1CM1 if dm2I1I2P3P4", 
"dm1CP3 if dm2I1I2P4M1", "dm1CP4 if dm2I1I2P3M1", "dm1dm2C if I1I2P3P4M1", 
"dm1dm2I1 if I2CP3P4M1", "dm1dm2I2 if I1CP3P4M1", "dm1dm2M1 if I1I2CP3P4", 
"dm1dm2P3 if I1I2CP4M1", "dm1dm2P4 if I1I2CP3M1", "dm1I1C if dm2I2P3P4M1", 
"dm1I1I2 if dm2CP3P4M1", "dm1I1M1 if dm2I2CP3P4", "dm1I1P3 if dm2I2CP4M1", 
"dm1I1P4 if dm2I2CP3M1", "dm1I2C if dm2I1P3P4M1", "dm1I2M1 if dm2I1CP3P4", 
"dm1I2P3 if dm2I1CP4M1", "dm1I2P4 if dm2I1CP3M1", "dm1P3M1 if dm2I1I2CP4", 
"dm1P3P4 if dm2I1I2CM1", "dm1P4M1 if dm2I1I2CP3", "dm2CM1 if dm1I1I2P3P4", 
"dm2CP3 if dm1I1I2P4M1", "dm2CP4 if dm1I1I2P3M1", "dm2I1C if dm1I2P3P4M1", 
"dm2I1I2 if dm1CP3P4M1", "dm2I1M1 if dm1I2CP3P4", "dm2I1P3 if dm1I2CP4M1", 
"dm2I1P4 if dm1I2CP3M1", "dm2I2C if dm1I1P3P4M1", "dm2I2M1 if dm1I1CP3P4", 
"dm2I2P3 if dm1I1CP4M1", "dm2I2P4 if dm1I1CP3M1", "dm2P3M1 if dm1I1I2CP4", 
"dm2P3P4 if dm1I1I2CM1", "dm2P4M1 if dm1I1I2CP3", "I1CM1 if dm1dm2I2P3P4", 
"I1CP3 if dm1dm2I2P4M1", "I1CP4 if dm1dm2I2P3M1", "I1I2C if dm1dm2P3P4M1", 
"I1I2M1 if dm1dm2CP3P4", "I1I2P3 if dm1dm2CP4M1", "I1I2P4 if dm1dm2CP3M1", 
"I1P3M1 if dm1dm2I2CP4", "I1P3P4 if dm1dm2I2CM1", "I1P4M1 if dm1dm2I2CP3", 
"I2CM1 if dm1dm2I1P3P4", "I2CP3 if dm1dm2I1P4M1", "I2CP4 if dm1dm2I1P3M1", 
"I2P3M1 if dm1dm2I1CP4", "I2P3P4 if dm1dm2I1CM1", "I2P4M1 if dm1dm2I1CP3", 
"P3P4M1 if dm1dm2I1I2C", "CP3P4M1 if dm1dm2I1I2", "dm1CP3M1 if dm2I1I2P4", 
"dm1CP3P4 if dm2I1I2M1", "dm1CP4M1 if dm2I1I2P3", "dm1dm2CM1 if I1I2P3P4", 
"dm1dm2CP3 if I1I2P4M1", "dm1dm2CP4 if I1I2P3M1", "dm1dm2I1C if I2P3P4M1", 
"dm1dm2I1I2 if CP3P4M1", "dm1dm2I1M1 if I2CP3P4", "dm1dm2I1P3 if I2CP4M1", 
"dm1dm2I1P4 if I2CP3M1", "dm1dm2I2C if I1P3P4M1", "dm1dm2I2M1 if I1CP3P4", 
"dm1dm2I2P3 if I1CP4M1", "dm1dm2I2P4 if I1CP3M1", "dm1dm2P3M1 if I1I2CP4", 
"dm1dm2P3P4 if I1I2CM1", "dm1dm2P4M1 if I1I2CP3", "dm1I1CM1 if dm2I2P3P4", 
"dm1I1CP3 if dm2I2P4M1", "dm1I1CP4 if dm2I2P3M1", "dm1I1I2C if dm2P3P4M1", 
"dm1I1I2M1 if dm2CP3P4", "dm1I1I2P3 if dm2CP4M1", "dm1I1I2P4 if dm2CP3M1", 
"dm1I1P3M1 if dm2I2CP4", "dm1I1P3P4 if dm2I2CM1", "dm1I1P4M1 if dm2I2CP3", 
"dm1I2CM1 if dm2I1P3P4", "dm1I2CP3 if dm2I1P4M1", "dm1I2CP4 if dm2I1P3M1", 
"dm1I2P3M1 if dm2I1CP4", "dm1I2P3P4 if dm2I1CM1", "dm1I2P4M1 if dm2I1CP3", 
"dm1P3P4M1 if dm2I1I2C", "dm2CP3M1 if dm1I1I2P4", "dm2CP3P4 if dm1I1I2M1", 
"dm2CP4M1 if dm1I1I2P3", "dm2I1CM1 if dm1I2P3P4", "dm2I1CP3 if dm1I2P4M1", 
"dm2I1CP4 if dm1I2P3M1", "dm2I1I2C if dm1P3P4M1", "dm2I1I2M1 if dm1CP3P4", 
"dm2I1I2P3 if dm1CP4M1", "dm2I1I2P4 if dm1CP3M1", "dm2I1P3M1 if dm1I2CP4", 
"dm2I1P3P4 if dm1I2CM1", "dm2I1P4M1 if dm1I2CP3", "dm2I2CM1 if dm1I1P3P4", 
"dm2I2CP3 if dm1I1P4M1", "dm2I2CP4 if dm1I1P3M1", "dm2I2P3M1 if dm1I1CP4", 
"dm2I2P3P4 if dm1I1CM1", "dm2I2P4M1 if dm1I1CP3", "dm2P3P4M1 if dm1I1I2C", 
"I1CP3M1 if dm1dm2I2P4", "I1CP3P4 if dm1dm2I2M1", "I1CP4M1 if dm1dm2I2P3", 
"I1I2CM1 if dm1dm2P3P4", "I1I2CP3 if dm1dm2P4M1", "I1I2CP4 if dm1dm2P3M1", 
"I1I2P3M1 if dm1dm2CP4", "I1I2P3P4 if dm1dm2CM1", "I1I2P4M1 if dm1dm2CP3", 
"I1P3P4M1 if dm1dm2I2C", "I2CP3 M1if dm1dm2I1P4", "I2CP3P4 if dm1dm2I1M1", 
"I2CP4M1 if dm1dm2I1P3", "I2P3P4M1 if dm1dm2I1C", "dm1CP3P4M1 if dm2I1I2", 
"dm1dm2CP3M1 if I1I2P4", "dm1dm2CP3P4 if I1I2M1", "dm1dm2CP4M1 if I1I2P3", 
"dm1dm2I1CM1 if I2P3P4", "dm1dm2I1CP3 if I2P4M1", "dm1dm2I1CP4 if I2P3M1", 
"dm1dm2I1I2C if P3P4M1", "dm1dm2I1I2M1 if CP3P4", "dm1dm2I1I2P3 if CP4M1", 
"dm1dm2I1I2P4 if CP3M1", "dm1dm2I1P3M1 if I2CP4", "dm1dm2I1P3P4 if I2CM1", 
"dm1dm2I1P4M1 if I2CP3", "dm1dm2I2CM1 if I1P3P4", "dm1dm2I2CP3 if I1P4M1", 
"dm1dm2I2CP4 if I1P3M1", "dm1dm2I2P3M1 if I1CP4", "dm1dm2I2P3P4 if I1CM1", 
"dm1dm2I2P4M1 if I1CP3", "dm1dm2P3P4M1 if I1I2C", "dm1I1CP3M1 if dm2I2P4", 
"dm1I1CP3P4 if dm2I2M1", "dm1I1CP4M1 if dm2I2P3", "dm1I1I2CM1 if dm2P3P4", 
"dm1I1I2CP3 if dm2P4M1", "dm1I1I2CP4 if dm2P3M1", "dm1I1I2P3M1 if dm2CP4", 
"dm1I1I2P3P4 if dm2CM1", "dm1I1I2P4M1 if dm2CP3", "dm1I1P3P4M1 if dm2I2C", 
"dm1I2CP3M1 if dm2I1P4", "dm1I2CP3P4 if dm2I1M1", "dm1I2CP4M1 if dm2I1P3", 
"dm1I2P3P4M1 if dm2I1C", "dm2CP3P4M1 if dm1I1I2", "dm2I1CP3M1 if dm1I2P4", 
"dm2I1CP3P4 if dm1I2M1", "dm2I1CP4M1 if dm1I2P3", "dm2I1I2CM1 if dm1P3P4", 
"dm2I1I2CP3 if dm1P4M1", "dm2I1I2CP4 if dm1P3M1", "dm2I1I2P3M1 if dm1CP4", 
"dm2I1I2P3P4 if dm1CM1", "dm2I1I2P4M1 if dm1CP3", "dm2I1P3P4M1 if dm1I2C", 
"dm2I2CP3M1 if dm1I1P4", "dm2I2CP3P4 if dm1I1M1", "dm2I2CP4M1 if dm1I1P3", 
"dm2I2P3P4M1 if dm1I1C", "I1CP3P4M1 if dm1dm2I2", "I1I2CP3M1 if dm1dm2P4", 
"I1I2CP3P4 if dm1dm2M1", "I1I2CP4M1 if dm1dm2P3", "I1I2P3P4M1 if dm1dm2C", 
"I2CP3P4M1 if dm1dm2I1", "dm1dm2CP3P4M1 if I1I2", "dm1dm2I1CP3M1 if I2P4", 
"dm1dm2I1CP3P4 if I2M1", "dm1dm2I1CP4M1 if I2P3", "dm1dm2I1I2CM1 if P3P4", 
"dm1dm2I1I2CP3 if P4M1", "dm1dm2I1I2CP4 if P3M1", "dm1dm2I1I2P3M1 if CP4", 
"dm1dm2I1I2P3P4 if CM1", "dm1dm2I1I2P4M1 if CP3", "dm1dm2I1P3P4M1 if I2C", 
"dm1dm2I2CP3M1 if I1P4", "dm1dm2I2CP3P4 if I1M1", "dm1dm2I2CP4M1 if I1P3", 
"dm1dm2I2P3P4M1 if I1C", "dm1I1CP3P4M1 if dm2I2", "dm1I1I2CP3M1 if dm2P4", 
"dm1I1I2CP3P4 if dm2M1", "dm1I1I2CP4M1 if dm2P3", "dm1I1I2P3P4M1 if dm2C", 
"dm1I2CP3P4M1 if dm2I1", "dm2I1CP3P4M1 if dm1I2", "dm2I1I2CP3M1 if dm1P4", 
"dm2I1I2CP3P4 if dm1M1", "dm2I1I2CP4M1 if dm1P3", "dm2I1I2P3P4M1 if dm1C", 
"dm2I2CP3P4M1 if dm1I1", "I1I2CP3P4M1 if dm1dm2", "dm1I2I1CP3P4M1 if dm2", 
"dm2dm1I1CP3P4M1 if I2", "dm2dm1I1I2CP3M1 if P4", "dm2dm1I1I2CP3P4 if M1", 
"dm2dm1I1I2CP4M1 if P3", "dm2dm1I1I2P3P4M1 if C", "dm2dm1I2CP3P4M1 if I1", 
"dm2I1I2CP3P4M1 if dm1"), key = c("Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", "Probability", 
"Probability", "Probability"), value = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.95, 1, 1, 0.96, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.96, 1, 0.94, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.96, 
0.95, 1, 1, 0.96, 0.95, 1, 0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.95, 
0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.95, 0.95, 1, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0.84, 0.95, 1, 1, 0.84, 0.95, 1, 0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.96, 0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.96, 1, 1, 0.95, 0.95, 
1, 1, 1, 0.95, 1, 1, 1, 0.96, 1, 0.96, 0.91, 0.88, 1, 0.95, 1, 
1, 0.91, 0.88, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.96, 1, 0.96, 1, 
0.95, 0.95, 1, 1, 0.9, 0.76, 0.84, 0.85, 0.96, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.7, 0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0.95, 0.95, 1, 1, 0.95, 0.91, 0.95, 1, 1, 0.95, 1, 1, 0.88, 
0.91, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1, 1, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95, 1, 0.91, 
0.91, 0.96, 0.75, 0.84, 0.84, 0.84, 0.95, 1, 0.78, 0.84, 0.84, 
0.7, 0.75, 0.84, 0.84, 0.7, 0.9, 0.95, 0.95, 1, 0.91, 0.91, 0.91, 
0.96, 0.91, 0.95, 0.84, 0.91, 0.96, 0.91, 0.86, 0.75, 0.84, 0.84, 
0.7, 0.86, 0.75)), row.names = c(NA, -254L), .Names = c("Type", 
"Combination", "key", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

With these two dataset, I run ggplot:

```
ggplot(bayes_TD6_H11_lw_Temp_fig, aes(x = forcats::fct_rev(factor(Combination, levels = comb, ordered = TRUE)))) +
  geom_line(aes(y = value, color = key, group = key)) +
  geom_point(aes(y = value, color = key)) +
  scale_x_discrete("Combination") +
  scale_y_continuous("p-value") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position='none') +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 5))
```

And I get this figure:

[image]

As you can see, the `y` axis has overlapping labels.

So my question is, how can I display alternate labels? That is, showing 1, omitting the other, showing the third...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand properly but you can specify a custom labeling function to `scale_x_discrete`, e.g.

```
scale_x_discrete("Combination", labels = function(breaks) {
    breaks[seq(2, length(breaks), 2)] <- ""
    breaks
  }) +
```