# Format date labels while also squashing gaps

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to do two things with `ggplot` that I've managed to figure out individually, but not in combination.

I've got data (percentage shares) for a randomly selected (but overall pretty dense, roughly 50%) subset of dates over about a year. I want to plot this as a barplot where:

1. Time gaps are ignored -- only the sequence of dates matters
2. Dates are formatted as `%b %d` for compactness

Here's some sample data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(34980)
DT = data.table(
  date = rep(.Date(17897 + 0:364), each = 4L),
  grp = factor(1:4),
  pct = rnorm(365L*4L)**2
)
# randomly eliminate about 60% of days
DT = DT[ , if (runif(1L) > .6) .SD, by = date]
# normalize to get actual percents & randomly make less than 1
DT[ , pct := pct/(sum(pct) + runif(.N, max = .1)), by = date]
```

Here's how I'd accomplish this using `base`+`data.table`:

```
DT[ , dcast(.SD, grp ~ date, value.var = 'pct')
    ][ , {
      y = .SD[ , !'grp']
      barplot(100*as.matrix(y), las = 2L,
              names.arg = format(as.IDate(names(y)), '%b %d'),
              col = 1:nrow(.SD), ylim = c(0, 100),
              main = 'Share over Time',
              ylab = 'Share (%)')
    }]
```

[image: base version]

`dcast` puts the `date` as a column name so it's essentially treated as a factor and we can use `as.IDate` (or `as.Date`) +`format` to reformat.

My attempts in `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(DT, aes(x = date, y = 100*pct, fill = grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  scale_x_date(labels = scales::date_format('%b %d'))
```

[image: bad ggplot 1]

This plot respects linearity in time leading to a lot of wasted space --> harder to read (does 2 but not 1).

Another attempt:

```
ggplot(DT, aes(x = factor(date), y = 100*pct, fill = grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

[image: bad ggplot 2]

This accomplishes 1 but not 2 -- you can see the x axis is quite garbled.

How can I do both 1 & 2? I tried this but no luck:

```
fkt_to_fmt = function(x) format(as.IDate(as.character(x)), format = '%b %d')
ggplot(DT, aes(x = factor(date), y = 100*pct, fill = grp)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
  scale_x_date(labels = fkt_to_fmt)
```

But I get an error back from `scales::date_trans` expecting a `Date` and the stack trace is not particularly illustrative for sussing out what I might change:

```
traceback()
16: stop("Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only", 
        call. = FALSE)
15: self$trans$transform(x)
14: f(..., self = self)
13: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
12: lapply(df[aesthetics], self$transform)
11: f(..., self = self)
10: s$transform_df(df = df)
9: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
8: lapply(scales$scales, function(s) s$transform_df(df = df))
7: unlist(lapply(scales$scales, function(s) s$transform_df(df = df)), 
       recursive = FALSE)
6: FUN(X[[i]], ...)
5: lapply(data, scales_transform_df, scales = scales)
4: ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
3: ggplot_build(x)
2: print.ggplot(x)
1: (function (x, ...) 
   UseMethod("print"))(x)
```

It seems I have no control over the `date` Transformer being used based on some playing around in `scale_x_date`.

Answer (score 1):

One hack could be displaying only specfic labels on X-axis. Idea from [@Gregor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31732767/3962914)

```
library(ggplot2)

DT$date <- format(DT$date, "%b %d")
DT$date <- factor(DT$date, levels = unique(DT$date))


ggplot(DT, aes(x = date, y = 100*pct, fill = grp)) +
    geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = levels(DT$date)[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 9))])
```

[image]

Here I am showing one label in every 10th value which can be changed/randomised based on preference. So here sequence of dates are preserved and no time gaps are observed in the plot.

Comment: oh I see, yes 