# scaling x axis isn't working, due to reorder?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale

I am trying to make a rank abundaunce curve. here's the head

```
head(rank)

    species     ab rank
792    PEGR2 462.10  792
1126    COUM 269.70 1126
1314    KRGR 207.04 1314
1439    KRER 177.11 1439
1446    PEBR 176.00 1446
1623  CAMI12 140.71 1623
```

the rank goes from 792-8538 with no kind of discrete pattern. I'm just trying to plot rank on the x axis with the abo n the y axis, but I can't get it to not just show all the ranks, rather than breaking it up, I don't know if it's because there isn't a pattern to the x axis or because I had to reorder it.

the x axis is numeric

here is my code

```
rank.abun <- ggplot(rank ,aes(x = reorder(rank, -ab), y = ab))+
  geom_line(stat = "identity")+
  #scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(792, 8538, 10))+
  labs(x = "Abundance Rank", y = "Abundance") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
```

and the corresponding plot [image]

Ideally, the x axis wouldn't have all of the labels.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732597/how-to-not-show-all-labels-on-ggplot-axis Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45147849/how-to-show-every-second-r-ggplot2-x-axis-label-value might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `scale_x_discrete()` you can specify what labels you want to put on the x axis, e.g.

```
library(tidyverse)

rank <- tribble(~"species", ~"ab", ~"rank",
"PEGR2", 462.10,  792,
"COUM", 269.70, 1126,
"KRGR", 207.04, 1314,
"KRER", 177.11, 1439,
"PEBR", 176.00, 1446,
"CAMI12", 140.71, 1623)

ggplot(rank, aes(x = reorder(rank, -ab), y = ab)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  labs(x = "Abundance Rank", y = "Abundance") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.line.x = element_blank(),
        axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c(792, 1623),
                   labels = c(792, 1623))
```

[image: example_1.png]

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with `scale_x_continuous` & the output of `reorder` is a `factor`. Detail explain in detail below

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)  
library(ggplot2)

# to understand we need to know what reorder does
# As you can see from the output below, it output a factor with Levels
with(rank, reorder(rank, -ab))
#> [1] 792  1126 1314 1439 1446 1623
#> attr(,"scores")
#>     792    1126    1314    1439    1446    1623 
#> -462.10 -269.70 -207.04 -177.11 -176.00 -140.71 
#> Levels: 792 1126 1314 1439 1446 1623

# And as it is a factor it will be treat as discrete value
# Therefore ggplot will display all value in the axis and
# your scale_x_continuous will causing error as it apply continuous to 
# discrete value
ggplot(rank, aes(x = reorder(rank, -ab), y = ab))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(792, 8538, 10))+
  labs(x = "Abundance Rank", y = "Abundance") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
#> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

**Note that as you reorder rank by ab, the data may not in continous order as they used to be therefore the plot would be confusing if people mistaken the x-Axis is continous while it's not.**

You may want to reconsider what you want to achieve here, what is the story you want to tell through your graph.

```
# Another way to visualize the order is using fill to visualized the rank
graph_data <- rank %>%
  # create a rank variable with negative ab value result
  # in biggest value rank 1st
  mutate(rank_ab = rank(-ab))
graph_data
#>   species     ab rank rank_ab
#> 1   PEGR2 462.10  792       1
#> 2    COUM 269.70 1126       2
#> 3    KRGR 207.04 1314       3
#> 4    KRER 177.11 1439       4
#> 5    PEBR 176.00 1446       5
#> 6  CAMI12 140.71 1623       6

ggplot(graph_data, aes(x = rank, y = ab))+
  # Then here graph data with fill geom_bar
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", mapping = aes(fill = rank_ab)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(792, 8538, 100))+
  labs(x = "Abundance Rank", y = "Abundance") +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    axis.line.x = element_blank(),
    axis.line.y = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>